# NSPredicate dont work with double values (%f)?

Tags: iphone, core-data

My managed object has 2 double fields: "latitude", "longitude".
I need to fetch all objects, that has certain coordinates

This code not working, fetchedObjects count = 0

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"latitude == %f AND longitude == %f", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude];
```

But this code work fine, fetchedObjects count = 3:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"latitude == 53.012667 AND longitude == 36.113000"];
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

it works fine with long float, %lf

Comment: As jdeprez stated you should not be comparing float values. Comparing float values is dangerous and bad practice. Instead, use a sizable region as a predicate, then calculate the distance from the point nearest to what you are searching for from the array of returned objects.

Answer (score 17):

Don't ever use `==` to compare floating point values.

If you want to find objects with a "specific" value, compare against a small range. Otherwise, floating-point representation error will bite you.

So consider using:

```
const float epsilon = 0.000001;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"latitude > %f AND latitude < %f AND longitude > %f AND longitude < %f", coordinate.latitude - epsilon,  coordinate.latitude + epsilon, coordinate.longitude - epsilon, coordinate.longitude + epsilon];
```

Comment: Clang's **float.h** defines a number of constants relevant to floats and doubles. Two of those are `FLT_EPSILON` (1E-5) and `DBL_EPSILON` (1E-9), which should be used instead of the epsilon 1E-6 given here. Characteristics of these constants are defined by [C99 5.2.4.2.2](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/5.2.4.2.2.html).

Comment: Use `%lf` if you're comparing against Doubles

Comment: Now `Double.ulpOfOne` rather than DBL_EPSILON (the latter is deprecated).

Answer (score 2):

It's because the precision of floats is not 100%. So you could also do this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"abs(latitude - %f) < 0.0001 AND abs(longitude - %f) < 0.0001", coordinate.latitude, coordinate.longitude]
```

Comment: I get this error message: ```'Invalid predicate', reason: 'The 'abs:' function is not supported.'```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to NSNumber using this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"latitude == %@ AND longitude == %@", @(coordinate.latitude), @(coordinate.longitude)];
```